# Why are my pedals not in the correct position

Tags: pedals

Why are my pedals not in the correct position? one is up the other is pointed forward. they should be 1 up and 1 down. Huffy Rock Creek Shimano

Comment: The pedals?  Or the crank arms?  A photo might show the problem better than words.

Answer (score 4):

Because they are installed wrong. You can remove one crank using crank puller and install it in correct position, or take it back to shop.

Comment: And if the pedals were right at one time but are no longer then likely one of the crank arms is loose.

Comment: (But I note that this is a BSO that might be sold at Walmart or some such, and the folks who prep bikes at such stores are often incompetent.  So getting a bike with the pedals installed wrong would not be incredibly unlikely.)

Comment: This made me chuckle a bit: "One bike for the ride and performance you deserve."